# mocha JSDOM testing on react, getElementById return null

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom

I'm using mocha and JsDom to test my react component.

First of all my component works perfectly, so it is problem with the testing enviornment.

Situation:

I have a component that render a couple of `select` tag with id. Then a `componentDidMount` in the component that would use `document.getElementById` to get those select tags and add options to them. But when I run my test, it is showing null for these `getElementById`.

Now if I comment out `componentDidMount`, and assert stuff such as below, it works perfectly, so the component did render out those select tags.

```
    describe('test component', function(){
      var renderedElement = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Component/>);
      var renderedNode = ReactDom.findDOMNode(renderedElement);
      it('should have the proper markup', function(){
        assert.equal(renderedNode.childElementCount, 5);
       [...]
      })
    })
```

what is causing the problem? Is it cause `document.getElementById` the document object doesn't exist in my testing environment cause Im using a 'fake' one, if so how should I test this?

below is my jsdom setup for mocha

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        var jsdom = require('jsdom'),
            baseHTML,
            window;

        if (!global.window) {
            baseHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head lang="en"><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Tests</title></head><body></body></html>';
            window = jsdom.jsdom(baseHTML).defaultView;

            global.window = window;
            global.document = window.document;
            global.navigator = window.navigator;
        }

    }());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the canonical way to get access to the mounted DOM component in React is to use a ref. Instead of using document.getElementById() in your componentDidMount instead use a `ref={(element) => { /* Do something with element like this.element = element to save it */ }}` on the element as you render it. This will get a correct callback with the mounted DOM element without the need to reference document.

Usage of document should be avoided if possible in React code as it makes it impossible to do universal rendering.